# Controlling thread count to balance CPU and IO waits in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there a way to figure out inside a .NET application whether I’m currently limited by CPU time or if IO is the bottleneck?

I'm querying a bunch of remote network services, the details of which don't really matter and can be abstracted as:

```
// perform a single  operation
if ( [randomness] ) {
    sleep(10s of seconds); // DNS/TCP connection timeout
} else {
    sleep(10s of miliseconds); // query a remote server
}
for x = 1…lots {
    // Do some CPU intensive work
}
```

While I have CPU available, I’d like to schedule as many of these as possible because they will spend a long time waiting for IO, but once the CPU is fully loaded I don’t want to keep spawning threads because that will cause performance to collapse. The total number of tasks is 'large'.

An obvious answer would be to just pick a ‘sensible’ number of concurrent threads as a tuning parameter, but this suffers from two problems:

- The length of the ‘sleep’ can vary massively between a LAN round trip and a TCP connection timeout, so the ratio of CPU work to IO wait time can vary by 3 orders of magnitude.
- The size of the machine this will run on can vary between a small single CPU VM to a heavy weight server-class machine.

In an ideal world the IO operations would all be replaced with asynchronous completion callbacks, but that isn't easy/possible in this case, because the network RPC is using existing, blocking code.

Comment: Have you looked into using IO Completion Ports?  They aren't related to threading per-se, so one thread can register a load of these without polluting the system with many threads: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/managediocp.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend two queues of thread, with the first handling the I/O calls and the second handling the post-I/O processing, because you are addressing two different problems.

For the I/O, I'd create a queue of threads that dump the I/O results into a secondary queue. You can queue up a large number of threads and set a throttle to the number of active ones, using a callback that signals when a thread finishes and launches the next one. You're limiting factor will be memory more than CPU, as running threads hold memory even when blocked (but not-yet-launched thread memory footprint is small).

The second queue can make use of `ThreadPool` or a separate cluster of your own threads. By having separate throttles you can adjust how many of both groups of threads are running, based upon average elapsed time or something like that.

If you make the second queue a database table, then you have an easy point at which to split the workload across multiple machines (or the cloud) and accumulate timing statistics.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of work you're actually better off using the async i/o pattern instead of spawning a bunch of threads (or using a lot of threadpool threads).

Basically this involves using the `BeginXxx` methods to make all the I/O calls which will only utilize an I/O completion port while waiting for the results.  When the result comes back, it'll trigger your callback on a threadpool thread.  The end result is that your code will only run leading up to the Begin call and when the result comes back.  You won't have any threads waiting on responses.

Comment: That would be the 'ideal' way, yes. The problem is that the library code that does the RPCs is written using blocking IO, so we can't (easily) re-write it to use non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use .NET 4 you could use the Task parallel library.

The TPL will manage the number of threads for you automatically (for CPU-bound operations) or you can constrain the maximum degree of parallelism when you need to (typically for I/O bound operations where you want to limit how many can happen at once).

In your case you might want to split the work into two Tasks and use a separate custom `TaskScheduler` for each so you have total control over how many threads are allocated and what CPU priority they run at (e.g. put all compute tasks on a below normal priority).

Schedule the I/O Task, then use `Task.ContinueWith` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321307.aspx) to schedule the computation part on a separate TaskScheduler.

(This might also be of some interest: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-task-parallel-library-with-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use a ThreadPool to manage all your threads and set a limit on the number of threads you are currently using.
There is an object in .NET called the PerformanceCounter in System.Diagnostics which will help you out.

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
```

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

public string getCurrentCpuUsage(){
            cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
}

public string getAvailableRAM(){
            ramCounter.NextValue()+"MB";
}

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, when copying things from emacs in linux I get this issue because of how my indenting and formatting are set up.